# Validate any number of input fields in a form

Tags: javascript, validation, input

I am trying to create validation for percentage input fields as shown in the link provided:
https://tinker.io/f5c2c/1

This currently works when you add values to BOTH fields. I want it so if you just add a value to one of these, the form still validates. In the JS you can see separate id's are required for each input field, when added and add to 100 it validates. I need it to work so you can have a number of empty fields are shown but just entering the data into any one of them and hitting submit will validate.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me like you've fallen into the [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) trap.

Why not use a [slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) from the jqueryui library? This should solve all your problems.

Comment: No, it has to be the way I presented in the original link.